# VS 2013 + Update 5 + EF 6.1 + Oracle

Tags: entity-framework, oracle11g, entity-framework-6, odac

I have question on connecting Oracle 11 from VS 2013 and Entity Framework 6.1.3 with Database First

Earlier our project developed using VS 2010 and connected oracle using entity framework.

Now, we are planning to upgrade to VS 2013 and Entity Framework 6.1.3. For that I have done the following steps:

1. Installed "32-bit Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio"
2. Added Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.dll
3. Tried to "ADO.NET Entity Data Model" but while adding the connection with the provider (Oracle Database (ODP.NET, Managed Drivers)). 
   I'm getting an exception "ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file". after this it is not allowing me to proceed further in this.

Also, I tried to create data connection using "Oracle Database (ODP.NET, UnManaged Drivers)", it is connecting but I'm not sure this approach is correct or will this lead to any other issue ?

Please suggests me how to connect to oracle 11 from VS 2013 with EF 6 and Database first approach..

I referred the following links for connecting the oracle from VS 2013

http://csharp.today/entity-framework-6-database-first-with-oracle/

http://totos-treasures.blogspot.com/2015/07/using-entityframework-with-oracle.html

Thanks,
Prakash.